# sql additional condition for where filter

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Person
id|name  |age|status
1 |Kelvin|12 |A     
2 |Calvin|13 |F

Books
id|personId|name  |status
1 |1       |Hello |A
2 |1       |Word  |F
```

This is how I select:

```
select *
from person as p
left join books as b on p.id = b.personid
where b.status = 'A' and b.status is null

id|name  |age|status|id   |personId|name |status
1 |Kelvin|12 |A     |1    |1       |Hello|A
2 |Kelvin|12 |A     |1    |1       |World|F
3 |Calvin|12 |F     |null |null    |null |null
```

The person has no book if the person status is F.

Is there any method to use `b.status is null` only when the person `p.status is F`?

Comment: Move the condition to the `on` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff example?

Comment: This query does not return the results that you posted. Post your expected results also.

Comment: **where b.status = 'A' and b.status is null** is always FALSE (there is no way for b.status to be 'A' and NULL at the same time

Comment: your query will work like inner join. please share output you are expecting.

Comment: shouldn't `where b.status = 'A' and b.status is null`  be `where b.status = null and p.status = 'F'` You kind of answered in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It was suggested that you move the b.status condition to the left-join ON clause such as

```
select *
   from 
      person p
         left join books b 
            on p.id = b.personid
            AND b.status = 'A' 
   where 
      b.status is null
```

So this forces the JOIN PORTION on the person and the status = 'A'.  The WHERE clause testing for NULL is only AFTER the left-join.  By having the AND b.status = 'A' forced the left-join to an explicit INNER join because it was a qualifier to the data.  By having the WHERE clause only test for the NULL is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The logic you are looking for is:

```
select *
from person p left join
     books b
     on p.id = b.personid ;
```

Your logic doesn't make sense at all -- because `b.status` cannot be both `'A'` and `NULL` at the same time.

There seems to be no need to check any of the statuses.  But if you don't want books where `person.status = 'F'` then:

```
select *
from person p left join
     books b
     on p.id = b.personid and p.status <> 'F';
```